# Try Except when Return from a function is False

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

This is my code for a number checker.

```
number = int(input("Give me a whole number. >> "))
standardNum = 50

def numberChecker(number, standardNum):
    result = standardNum - number
    print(result)
    if result >= 0:
        print("Result is positive.")
        return True
    else:
        print("Result is negative.")
        return False

while True:
    try:
        numberChecker(number, standardNum)
        break
    except numberChecker() == True:
        print("Your number is too big.")
        amountProduct = int(input("Give me a whole small number >> "))
```

When I give the input as "80", this is what I see -

```
Give me a whole number. >> 80
-30
Result is negative.
```

However, it does not print the block of code underneath the except numberChecker() line. 

I want the code to print "Your number is too big" and ask for another input with the sentence "Give me a whole small number >>" but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried changing the conditions from True to False but that still had no effect!

Can someone help? Please!
Many thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be using exception handling... there are no exceptions being thrown here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `try-except` blocks are meant for. You clearly should be using an `if-else`:

```
while True:
    if numberChecker(number, standardNum):
        break
    else:
        print("Your number is too big.")
        number = int(input("Give me a whole small number >> "))
```

Comment: But then if I want to reprompt the user to enter a new number, I can't use the if-else statement. What other alternative method could I use?

Comment: Fantastic! I'll tick your answer as soon as the time limit has ended! Thanks very much! Please up rate my question for other users to benefit if possible!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to formulate this value check, but if you want to use exceptions, this approach is just a small leap from where you are now:

```
standardNum = 50

def numberChecker(number, standardNum):
    if number > standardNum:
        raise ValueError

    return True

while True:
    my_number = int(input("Give me a small whole number: "))

    try:
        if numberChecker(my_number, standardNum):
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Your number is too big.")
```

Comment: That is also a valid approach. Much appreciated! Thanks! I will also include that as another version of my code!

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you understand the purpose of exceptions. With that said, here's a better way to misuse them may accomplish what you're attempting to do:

```
STANDARD_NUM = 50

class NumberTooBigError(Exception): pass

def numberChecker(number, standardNum):
    result = standardNum - number
    if result < 0:  # number >= standardNum
        raise NumberTooBigError()

while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Give me a whole number. >> "))
        numberChecker(number, STANDARD_NUM)
        break
    except NumberTooBigError:
        print("Your number is too big.")

print("Your number was accepted.")
```

Sample usage:

```
Give me a whole number. >> 80
Your number is too big.
Give me a whole number. >> 55
Your number is too big.
Give me a whole number. >> 50
Your number was accepted.
```